# Relation between (the $2 \pi$ in) Gauss-Bonnet and in Cauchy's differentation formula

Tags: complex-analysis, differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, complex-geometry, pi

When I 1st saw Gauss-Bonnet, I was wondering if this $2 \pi$ had any relation with the $2 \pi$ in [Cauchy's differentiation formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%27s_integral_formula#Theorem). Maybe a better question is to ask about the relation between Gauss-Bonnet and Cauchy's differentiation formula. I recall the $2 \pi$ ([or $\tau$](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IF1zcRoOVN0)) in Cauchy's differentiation formula is to do with homotopy with a circle in the original Cauchy's integral formula. I guess Gauss-Bonnet will have something to do with circles or spheres. So far I know only some basic version of Gauss-Bonnet and not yet its generalisations.

Okay so not exactly any question yet ummm...

1. Where does the $2 \pi$ come from in Gauss-Bonnet? Is it something to do with circles or spheres (Or $S^n$)?
2. Is the $2 \pi$ in Gauss-Bonnet related to the $2 \pi$ in Cauchy's differentiation formula?
3. What's the relation of Gauss-Bonnet with Cauchy's differentiation formula?

Comment: If you see $\pi$ it *always* has something to do with circles - though sometimes that circle is extremely well-hidden.

Answer (score 5):

In some sense, the answer is yes, there is a relation, passing through [Riemann-Roch theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann%E2%80%93Roch_theorem) (two corollaries of it, actually). Indeed, one can prove Gauss-Bonnet (at least for Riemann surfaces$^1$) with Cauchy and RR.

Proof:
On a Riemannian surface we can always find local coordinates, in which the metric tensor is conformal and the Gaussian curvature take the particularly easy form

$$\mathbf{g}=\frac12\lambda^2(z,\overline{z}) (dz\otimes d\overline{z}+d\overline{z}\otimes dz)=\lambda^2(dx\otimes dx+dy\otimes dy)\\
K=-\frac1{\lambda^2}\Delta\log(\lambda)$$

By partition of unity, we can glue them to a global construction. The volume form $dS$ takes the form $dS=\lambda^2 dx\wedge dy$, and thus we obtain

$$KdS=-\Delta \log(\lambda)dx\wedge dy$$

Using [Dolbeaut's operators](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_differential_form#The_Dolbeault_operators) we can write it as
$$KdS=2id(\partial \log(\lambda))$$
Now, given a differential meromorphic $1-$form $\omega$ (which exists thanks to RR), one can prove that, writing locally $\omega=fdz$, the expression $$\varphi=\frac{\lambda}{|f|}$$
defines a meromorphic function. Since in particular $\ln(|f|)$ is harmonic, we can write
$$KdS=2id(\partial\log(\varphi))$$

Now, to the Gauss-Bonnet theorem: writing $X_\varepsilon$ as the riemann surface minus small "discs" $D_{k,\varepsilon}$ around the singularities $z_k$ of $\varphi$, we have

$$\int_X KdS=\lim_{\varepsilon\to 0}\int_{X_\varepsilon}2id(\partial \log(\varphi))=\lim_{\varepsilon\to 0}
2i\int_{\partial X_\varepsilon}\partial \log(\varphi)=\lim_{\varepsilon\to 0}\sum _k\int_{\partial D_{k,\varepsilon}}\partial \log(\varphi)
$$

Now, near the singularities of $\varphi$, i.e. the poles or zeros of $f$, we can write $\varphi$ as $\frac{\psi}{|z|^m}$. Thus, **by Cauchy's integral formula**
$$\lim_{\varepsilon\to 0}\int_{\partial D_{k,\varepsilon}}\partial \log(\varphi)=\lim_{\varepsilon\to 0}-m_k\int_{\partial D_{k,\varepsilon}}\partial \log(|z|)=\lim_{\varepsilon\to 0}-\frac {m_k}{2}\int_{\partial D_{k,\varepsilon}}\frac{dz}{z}=-\pi im_k$$

Since, by RR, the degree of the canonical divisor is $2g-2$ and $\sum m_k=-\text{deg}(\omega)$
Thus we get

$$\int_X KdS=-2\pi \text{deg}(\omega)=2\pi (2-2g)=2\pi \chi(X)$$

$^1:$ One can actually prove, though it is much harder, that every orientable surface admits such a local coordinates system, called [isothermal coordinates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isothermal_coordinates#:%7E:text=Korn%20and%20Lichtenstein%20proved%20that,and%20of%20the%20Cotton%20tensor.). The usual proofs relies on the solution of the [Beltrami equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beltrami_equation)

Answer (score 1):

The Gauss-Bonnet theorem can be seen as a limiting continuous case of a simpler theorem, to do with surfaces made out glued-together polygons. To each point $p$ on such a surface, we can measure the angle $\theta(p)$ "visible" around $p$. If $p$ lies on a face or an edge we have $\theta(p) = 2\pi$, but on the corners things are different: if $p$ lies on the corner of a cube then $\theta(p) = 3 \pi / 2$ for example, while a point on the corner of a tetrahedron would have the visible angles adding to $\theta(p) = \pi$. We could also imagine gluing together "too many" polygons along their edges, to get a point with $\theta(p) > 2 \pi$.

Define the *angle defecit* at a point to be $\delta(p) = 2\pi - \theta(p)$, so $\delta(p) = 0$ for everything except corner points, where it measures "deviation" from being flat. Then we have a discrete analogue of the Gauss-Bonnet theorem: for any polygonal surface $S$,
$$ \sum_{p \in S} \delta(p) = 2 \pi \chi(S),$$
where $\chi(S)$ is the Euler characteristic of $S$. We can quickly check this for the tetrahedron for example: $\delta(p) = \pi$ at the four corner points, so we have $\sum_{p \in S} \delta(p) = 4 \pi$. On the other hand, the Euler characteristic of a tetrahedron is $2$, since it is homeomorphic to a sphere. Of course the wonderful thing is that no matter how you assemble polygons to make a (orientable) surface, the sum of the angle defecits only depends on the underlying topology. You can read more about this in the wonderful book *[Mostly Surfaces](http://www.math.brown.edu/%7Eres/MathNotes/surface.pdf)* by Richard Evan Schwartz.

The differential geometry version of Gauss-Bonnet is some kind of limiting version of the above: the Gaussian curvature $K$ is the infinitesimal version of the angle defecit, and we have
$$ \int_{S} K \, dA = 2 \pi \chi(S).$$
The interpretation of the $2 \pi$ here being an angle also makes sense from dimensional analysis: area has units of $[\mathrm{length}]^2$ while Gaussian curvature has units of $[\mathrm{length}]^{-2}$, so the integral of one over the other should be dimensionless. (A good rule of thumb is to always assume that a $2 \pi$ appearing in a dimensionless quantity is an angle).

---

As for Cauchy's integral formula, I feel that the spirit of the question is the following: why is it true that $\oint_C \frac{dz}{z} = 2 \pi i$ for any closed curve $C$ encircling the origin counter-clockwise, and where does the $2 \pi$ come from? Again the $2 \pi$ appearing is an angle, and the quantity being counted is called the *winding number*: if $C$ were to wrap around the origin twice, we would get $4 \pi i$. Imagine standing at the origin and watching the curve $C$ being traced out: when it closes in on itself, you may have turned around a net $n$ times, and the result of the integral will be $2 \pi n i$.

---

I cannot myself draw a direct connection between them further than this: The $2 \pi$ appearing in each is an angle, and they are both theorems relating complicated things (differential geometry, or contour integration) to simpler topological things (Euler characteristic, or winding number).